# A connection pool error in CloudBees Java EE/Glassfish 4 Full plateform

Tags: jms, cloudbees, glassfish-4, java-ee-7, broker

CloudBees is add a new Java EE 7/Glassfish 4 Full plateform in their clickstart. If I understand correctly, this mean that it support all Java EE 7 features(contain JMS app). But when I run my JMS app, it log a error "Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool"

This is my code, it work in my localhost:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ReceiverBean {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ReceiverBean");
    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;
    @Resource(lookup = "java:comp/jms/webappQueue")
    private Queue queue;
   .....

public void getMessage() {
        try {
            JMSConsumer receiver = context.createConsumer(queue);
            String text = receiver.receiveBody(String.class, 1000);

            if (text != null) {
                FacesMessage facesMessage =
                        new FacesMessage("Reading message: " + text);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
            } else {
                FacesMessage facesMessage =
                        new FacesMessage("No message received after 1 second");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
            }
        } catch (JMSRuntimeException t) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "ReceiverBean.getMessage: Exception: {0}",
                    t.toString());
        }
    }
```

The log of glassfish in CloudBees console:

> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:43.737+0000|INFO|glassfish
>   4.0|javax.enterprise.resource.jms.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(1);_TimeMillis=1384846603737;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=addresslist.setjmsservice.provider;|
>   JMS010: ADDRESSLIST in setJmsServiceProvider: mq://localhost:0/|#]
>
> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:43.738+0000|INFO|glassfish
>   4.0|javax.enterprise.resource.jms.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(1);_TimeMillis=1384846603738;_LevelValue=800;_MessageID=jms.connection.url;|
>   JMS08: JMS Service Connection URL is : mq://localhost:0/|#]
>
> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:44.552+0000|INFO|glassfish
>   4.0|javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(1);_TimeMillis=1384846604552;_LevelValue=800;|
>   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter: Version:  5.0 
>   (Build 14-e) Compile:  April 12 2013 0104|#]
>
> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:44.559+0000|INFO|glassfish
>   4.0|javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(1);_TimeMillis=1384846604559;_LevelValue=800;|
>   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter starting: broker is
>   EMBEDDED, connection mode is Direct|#]
>
> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:44.847+0000|INFO|glassfish
>   4.0|imq.log.Logger|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(1);_TimeMillis=1384846604847;_LevelValue=800;|
>   [B1002]: An existing property file for imqbroker was not found, no
>   stored properties will be loaded |#]
>
> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:45.558+0000|SEVERE|glassfish
>   4.0||_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-4;_TimeMillis=1384846605558;_LevelValue=1000;|
>   Broker exiting.|#]
>
> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:45.562+0000|INFO|glassfish
>   4.0|javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.lifecycle|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(1);_TimeMillis=1384846605562;_LevelValue=800;|
>   MQJMSRA_RA1101: GlassFish MQ JMS Resource Adapter Started:EMBEDDED|#]
>
> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:49.808+0000|WARNING|glassfish
>   4.0|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(2);_TimeMillis=1384846609808;_LevelValue=900;_MessageID=poolmgr.get_connection_failure;|
>   RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [
>   jms/__defaultConnectionFactory-Connection-Pool ]. Reason :
>   com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException|#]
>
> [#|2013-11-19T07:36:49.811+0000|SEVERE|glassfish
>   4.0|SenderBean|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(2);_TimeMillis=1384846609811;_LevelValue=1000;|
>   SenderBean.sendMessage: Exception:
>   com.sun.messaging.jms.MQRuntimeException: MQRA:DCF:allocation
>   failure:createConnection:Error in allocating a connection. Cause:
>   null|#]

Anyone could tell me why?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees supports the web profile on the Glassfish stack, see [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack). JMS is only supported on the [full profile](https://glassfish.java.net/webprofileORfullplatform31x.html), see here.

You can try the Glassfish 3 full profile [here](https://github.com/cyrille-leclerc/glassfish3-full-clickstack). It is a community stack.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But in "clickStart" of your web, I see you have a "Glassfish 4 Full App". Is it a full profile?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was released around two weeks ago. Nicolas has already improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Glassfish 4 Full Profile" clickstack is a work in progress, it doesn't support JMS yet, neither does it support distributed EJB or comparable JavaEE stuff.